# How to use a variable as part of a regular expression in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) parts of a file path starting at a string value that is contained in a variable. Let me explain this in an abstracted example.

Let's assume this path: /docs/reports/test reports/document1.docx

Using a regular expression I can get the required string like so:
`'^.*(?=\/test\s)'`

https://regex101.com/r/6mBhLX/5

The resulting string is '/test reports/document1.docx'.

Now, for this to work I have to use the literal string 'test'. However, I would like to know how to use a variable that contains 'test', e.g. $myString.

I already looked at *[How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)*, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt this for PowerShell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest using `$([regex]::escape($myString))` inside a double quoted string literal:

```
$myString="[test]"
$pattern = "^.*(?=/$([regex]::escape($myString))\s)"
```

Or, in case you do not want to worry with additional escaping, use a regular concatenation using `+` operator:

```
$pattern = '^.*(?=/' + [regex]::escape($myString) +'\s)'
```

The resulting `$pattern` will look like `^.*(?=/\[test]\s)`. Since the `$myString` variable is a literal string, you need to escape all special regex metacharacters (with `[regex]::escape()`) that may be inside it for the regex engine to interpret it as literal chars.

In your case, you may use

```
$s = '/docs/reports/test reports/document1.docx'
$myString="test"
$pattern = "^.*(?=/$([regex]::escape($myString))\s)"
$s -replace $pattern
```

Result: `/test reports/document1.docx`

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code in PowerShell but unfortunately, it didn't return anything (no error though). I used the exact code you provided and then:

"/docs/reports/test reports/document1.docx" | Select-String -Pattern $pattern

Comment: @colonel_claypoo What did you expect to get?

Comment: My goal was to achieve the same as in this example: [link](https://regex101.com/r/6mBhLX/5). The matching string "/docs/reports" is trimmed from the original string "/docs/reports/test reports/document1.docx" if I use Select-String in PowerShell. Sorry, if was had been a little unclear in my initial post.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo If  you want to get `/test reports/document1.docx`, use `$myString="test"` and then `$s -replace $pattern`

Comment: I appreciate it. It basically works but one thing I noticed is that once I change the search term from 'test' to 'test reports' the expression doesn't work anymore. I added *. after \s to allow for any following character in the pattern.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo [`^.*(?=\/test reports\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/Zi7mkx/1/) cannot match anything in `/docs/reports/test reports/document1.docx` because `\s` requires a whitespace after `reports`, but there is a `/`. You may [try with a word boundary, `\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Zi7mkx/2). Note that using an optional pattern (pattern that may match an empty string, like `\s*`) at the end of the lookahead is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that absolutely helped. I looked it up as well and it makes more sense to me know so I can agree that \s* at the end is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

[Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210893/45375) provides the crucial pointer:

Use **[`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape)** in order to escape a string for safe inclusion in a regex (regular expression) so that it is treated as a *literal*;
e.g., `[regex]::Escape('$10?')` yields `\$10\?` - the characters with special meaning to a regex were `\`-escaped.

However, **I suggest using `'...'`**, i.e., building the regex from ***single*-quoted aka [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)**:

```bash
$myString='test'
$regex = '^.*(?=/' + [regex]::escape($myString) + '\s)'
```

<sup>Using the `-f` operator - `$regex = '^.*(?=/{0}'\s)' -f [regex]::Escape($myString)` works too and is perhaps visually cleaner, but note that `-f` - unlike string concatenation with `+` - is culture-*sensitive*, which can lead to different results.</sup>

**Using `'...'` strings in regex contexts in PowerShell is a good habit to form**:

- By avoiding **`"..."`**, so-called [*expandable* strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), you **avoid additional up-front interpretation** (interpolation a.k.a expansion) of the string, which can have unexpected effects, given that **`$` has special meaning in *both* contexts**: the start of
  a variable reference or subexpression when string-expanding, and the end-of-input marker in regexes.
- Using `"..."` can be **especially tricky** in the ***substitution operand*** of the regex-based 
  **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator**, where tokens such as `$1` refer to *capture-group results*, and if you used `"$1"`, PowerShell would try to expand a `$1` *PowerShell variable*, which presumably doesn't exist, resulting in the *empty string*.

  - For a concise, but comprehensive overview of PowerShell's `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

Comment: Based on the directions contained herein, I devised my as regex as follows for my powershell script.  $regex = '^'+[regex]::escape($pageno)+'\s+|^1$'  Here $pageno is a variable that goes on incrementing from 1. I also changed to using single quotes rather than double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the variable within double quotes ("pattern"), like this:

```
PS > $pattern = "^\d+\w+"
PS > "357test*&(fdnsajkfj" -match $pattern          # return true
PS > "357test*&(fdnsajkfj" -match "$pattern.*\w+$"  # return true
PS > "357test*&(fdnsajkfj" -match "$pattern\w+$"    # return false
```

Please have a try. :)

Comment: This won't help the OP, because they want to include an unknown variable value in a regex pattern while ensuring that the value is treated as a _literal_. In other words: a mechanism is needed that _escapes_ any incidental regex metacharacters in the value.