# Match true or false between strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to create a regex that works with the `-match` operator. The following already works:

```bsh
# Exact match
$string1 = [Regex]::Escape('C:\Fruit\kiwi')
$regex = [regex] '^{0}$' -f $string1
'C:\Fruit\kiwi' -match $regex

# Match where trail is allowed ( -like 'c:\folder*')
$string1 = [Regex]::Escape('C:\Fruit\kiwi')
$regex = [regex] '^{0}' -f $string1
'C:\Fruit\kiwi\other folder' -match $regex
```

Now we're trying to have a match when there is something between two strings, but this fails:

```bsh
# Match in between strings
$string1 = [Regex]::Escape("C:\Fruit")
$string2 = [Regex]::Escape("\kiwi")
$regex = [regex] '(?is)(?<=\b{0}\b)+?(?=\b{1}\b)' -f $string1, $string2
'C:\Fruit\d\kiwi' -match $regex
```

According to the docs it says:

> - '*'  matches 0 or more times
> - '+'  matches 1 or more times
> - '?'  matches 1 or 0 times
> - '*?' matches 0 or more times, but as few as possible
> - '+?' matches 1 or more times, but as few as possible

So I was expecting that anything between `C:\Fruit` and `\kiwi` would result in `true` but this is not the case. What are we doing wrong? We're only after true false, because in the end we will glue these pieces together like `regex1|regex2|..`.

Comment: `.+?` matches 1 or more chars as few as possible. You quantified the lookbehind. You must quantify a consuming pattern instead, the `.`.

Comment: How to have it return `true` when there is something between the strings and `false` when there's nothing between them?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/9nxPPm/1. You just missed the `.`. BUT I suspect you will have issues due to `\b` word boundary as well. Try without them, `'(?is)(?<={0}).+?(?={1})'`

Comment: [Tried without word boundaries yet](https://regex101.com/r/9nxPPm/2) - `'(?is)(?<={0}).+?(?={1})'`?

Comment: This works `(?is)(?<=C:\\Fruit).+?(?=\\kiwi)` but the issue is I can't insert the escaped strings in here. The following fails: `(?is)(?<={0}).+?(?={1})`

Comment: Indeed, when fully typed out like in your proposal it is indeed working. However, not when the 2 strings are added to the regex string later.

Comment: So your problem is also how to build a pattern out of variables?

Comment: I guess so, as `$string1` and `$string2` are PowerShell variables.

Comment: `$regex = [regex] "(?is)(?<=$string1).+?(?=$string2)"`, then `'C:\Fruit\kiwi' -match $regex` yields *false* and `'C:\Fruit\d\kiwi' -match $regex` yields *true*

Comment: Perfect! That's it! Thank you very much. If you post it as an asnwer I'll mark it as solved. Weird that it can't be inserted with the `-f` operator. Anyhow, it's fixed, thank you :)

Comment: It can be inserted with the `-f` operator, you just need to provide parenthesis around the expression, that you are casting to `[regex]`: `$regex = [regex]('(?is)(?<={0}).+?(?={1})' -f $string1, $string2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix your current code by using

```
$regex = [regex] "(?is)(?<=$string1).+?(?=$string2)"
```

Here,

- `.+?`  is used to match any 1+ chars as few as possible, you need to quantify a consuming pattern, not a lookbehind
- Use double quotation marks to form the string literal in order to support string interpolation. Also, see more options at [How to use a variable as part of a regular expression in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210739)
- You should remove `\b` word boundaries as they are context dependent (you may add any further restrictions later if need be).