# In PowerShell how do I use regex to validate input to include any character including backslashes?

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to validate an input.

I want the input to be either blank, or allow for entries surrounded by single quotes separated by a comma, allowing for one, two, or more entries with any characters and any length between the single quotes. ex: `'one','two','three','\four','.dog','cat'`

If I use this:

```
$string = Read-Host "Enter a string"
$pattern = "^$|^'\w+'(,'(\w+)')*$"
if ($string -match $pattern) {
    Write-Host "The string meets the pattern."
} else {
    Write-Host "The string DOES NOT meet the pattern."
}
```

For empty entry this works fine: `^$|`

`^'\w+'(,'(\w+)')*$` works for characters a-z,A-Z,0-9. But how do I allow for any character entry, including backslashes, periods and other special characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls use `$pattern = "^$|^'[^']*'(,'[^']*')*$"`.

`[^']*` matches any character except the single quote ('). It allows for any character `between the single quotes`, including `backslashes, periods, and other special characters`.

- `^$|^` =>  either an empty string or the following pattern.
- `'[^']*'` => `'`: matches the opening single quote. `^`: negates the character class, `*`: means zero or more occurrences. So, `[^']*` matches any character except the single quote ('). `'`: matches the closing single quote.
- `(,'[^']*')*` => for a comma-separated list of single-quoted strings (zero or more times).
- `*$` => for the entire pattern to repeat zero or more times.

Sample Code:

```
$string = Read-Host "Enter a string"
$pattern = "^$|^'[^']*'(,'[^']*')*$"
if ($string -match $pattern) {
    Write-Host "The string meets the pattern."
} else {
    Write-Host "The string DOES NOT meet the pattern."
}
```

Sample Outputs:

```
Enter a string: 'one','two','three','\four','.dog','cat'
The string meets the pattern.

Enter a string:
The string meets the pattern.

Enter a string: '.dog','\cat'
The string meets the pattern.
```

Comment: beat me to it with the same exact pattern haha, tho I think `'[^']*'` should be `'[^']+'` unless OP wants to allow `''` as input. Might need feedback on his side on that.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Good point, thank you. Yes, that is a fair consideration. It is best to not allow for `''` as input.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the **question implied by the post's *title***:

- It is the `.` [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) [metacharacter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) that represents *any* character - albeit by default excluding `\n`, i.e. a Unix-format *newline*, technically a LF character (LINE FEED, [`U+000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a)).

  - To make `.` also match the latter, enable the single-line [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options): place `(?s)` at the start of the regex (in the simplest case, to apply to the *entire* expression).
- Using a *negated* character class, such as `[^']` to match anything *but* `'`, implicitly matches a newline too, even without setting the single-line option.

  - Independently of whether `.` matches newlines or not, a run of characters - `.*` (if possibly empty) or `.+` (if xnon-empty) - can be qualified with `?` to make matching *non-greedy*, so that, in the (single-line) case at hand, `.+?` is an alternative to `[^']+`, i.e. matches only up to (but excluding) the *closest* `'` char., if any.

---

As for a **specific solution**, to  provide an alternative to [Ömer Sezer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77669106/45375):

- The following regex uses a *single* capture group (`(...)`) to capture all tokens in the input string:

  - `^(?:'([^']+)',?)*$` - [explanation on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HqGG0T/1)
  - The above tolerates a *trailing* `,` - to avoid that, use:

    - `^(?:'([^']+)'(?:,(?!$))?)*$` - [explanation on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HqGG0T/2)
- In combination with using [`[regex]::Match()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-match(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions)) in lieu of [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), this allows you to *extract the  individual tokens* represented in the input string, as shown next:

```bash
$string = Read-Host 'Enter a string'

$match = [regex]::Match($string, "^(?:'([^']+)',?)*$")
if ($match.Success) {

  Write-Verbose -Verbose ('The string matches, ' + ('but is empty.', 'with the following tokens:')[[bool] $match.Value])
  $match.Groups[1].Captures.Value

} else {

  Write-Warning "The string does NOT match the pattern."

}
```

Note:

- Accessing `.Groups[1]` on the [`[Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instance returned by `[regex]::Match()` returns what the *first* (and only) capture group captured:

  - `.Captures` accesses the collection of the *multiple instances* of the capture-group matches, themselves expressed as `[Match]` instances.
  - `.Value` uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract the *matched text* from each instance.
- While the use of `"..."` is convenient *here* - because it allows use of `'` *without escaping* - it is **generally preferable to use `'...'` to represent regexes**, i.e. [*verbatim* string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216562/45375).

Sample output, with `'foo','bar','baz'` provided as verbatim input to the `Read-Host` command:

```
VERBOSE: The string matched, with the following tokens:
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Great answer as well, thank you for taking time to explain!

Comment: Glad to hear you think so, @HTWingNut; my pleasure.