# Match all characters between two commas or between ," and ", with regex powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

Using powershell regex I would like it to find the first match between two commas or between ," and ",

Example:

```
"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? fish, meat or\n eggs?",""
"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?",""
0x00030002,What do you want to eat?,
```

I want it to become:

```
What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?
What do you want to eat?
What do you want to eat?
```

I tried this code but it doesn't behave correctly:

`(?<=,"|\?<=,).*(?=",.*?|\?=,.*?)`

Comment: You could use a capture group with the same name and an alternation if the formats are not matched, not taking nested double quotes into account `^(?:"[^"]*","(?<val>[^"]*)"|[^,]*,(?<val>.*?(?=,+(?:[^,\s)]|$))))` https://regex101.com/r/gsev4v/1

Comment: Then use `(?<=(,")|,(?!")).*?(?(1)(?=",)|(?=,(?!")))`

Comment: The most recent edit to your sample input (`\n`) makes no difference with respect to the answers already given, because `\n` is treated _verbatim_ in PowerShell string literals. If, by contrast, what you _meant_ was to have  `\n` represent an _actual newline_ (line break): Please do NOT make fundamental changes to your requirements _after answers have been given_: it invalidates these answers and confuses future readers; ask a new question instead. However, note that iRon's CSV-parsing answer  would work even with the changed requirements - another good reason to parse CSV data as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match:

```
(?<=,")[^"]*(?=",)|(?<=,)(?!")[^,]*(?<!")(?=,)
```

Among other things, this matches the following:

```
"0x00030002","What do you, want to eat?",""
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0x00030002,What do "you want" to eat?,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and does not match:

```
"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?,"
0x00030002 ,What do you want to eat?",
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BoW2Ce/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=,")  # positive lookbehind asserts current location is preceded by ,"
[^"]*    # match zero or more characters other than "
(?=",)   # positive lookahead asserts current location is followed by ",
|        # or
(?<=,)   # positive lookbehind asserts current location is preceded by ,
(?!")    # negative lookahead asserts current location is not followed by "
[^,]*    # match zero or more characters other than ,
(?<!")   # negative lookbehind asserts current location is not preceded by "
(?=,)    # positive lookahead asserts current location is followed by ,
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using a regular expression for this (which has some pitfalls), I would use the native [`ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) for this:

```
$List = @'
"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?",""
'"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?",""
0x00000000,What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?,
0x00030002,What do you want to eat?,
"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? ""fish"", ""meat"" or ""eggs?"""
'@ -Split '\r?\n'

$List | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Hex, String, Rest | Select-Object -Expand String

What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?
What do you want to eat?
What do you want to eat? fish
What do you want to eat?
What do you want to eat? "fish", "meat" or "eggs?"
```

Answer (score 1):

As an aside:

- Given that your input seems to be well-formed CSV data, [iRon's helpful CSV-parsing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77937104/45375) is well worth considering for conceptual elegance and robustness (though it'll be slower than a regex solution).
  Notably, it also handles *multiline* field values enclosed in `"..."` correctly, as well es *escaped embedded `"` values* (`""`), which it automatically *unescapes*.

As for a regex solution:

**tl;dr**

The following directly returns the desired values, stripped of any enclosing double quotes:

```bash
@(
  '"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?",""',
  '"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?",""',
  '0x00030002,What do you want to eat?,'
) -replace '^(?:("?)(.*?)\1(?:,|$)){2}.*$',
           '$2'
```

Explanation:

- `("?)(.*?)\1(?:,|$)` matches *one* (single-line) field value in your CSV-like input, with the 2nd capture-group (`(.*?)`) capturing the raw (unquoted) field value; matching this pattern *repeatedly*, with a *duplication expression* such as `{2}`, allows you to extract any (single-line) field value of interest (see details below).

  - Unlike iRon's CSV solution, this approach does *not* handle multiline field values and embedded `"` chars. escaped as `""` inside `"..."`-enclosed fields; a solution that does requires a significantly more complex regex, as shown in the bottom section.
- If you make your regex match each input string *in full*, you can take advantage of PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to *combine matching with extracting*:

  - The regex operand that matches each input string in full, while capturing the 2nd field value (too) (`{2}`), without enclosing `"..."` (if present), in what happens to be the 2nd capture group (`(…)`):

    - `^(?:("?)(.*?)\1(?:,|$)){2}.*$`
    - The solution below uses an annotated version of this regex, spread across multiple lines for readability, via `(?x)`, the inline form of the [`IgnoreWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Whitespace) regex option.
    - For a more detailed explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/QJVvG7/4).
  - The substitution operand that replaces the full input string with the (last instance of) what the 2nd capture group captured:

    - `$2`

```bash
# Sample input lines.
$inputLines = @(
  '"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?",""',
  '"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?",""',
  '0x00030002,What do you want to eat?,'
)

# Directly extracts the substring of interest from each input line.
$inputLines -replace '(?x) # Parsing option: 
                           # x = allow insignificant whitespace and comments
  ^           # Start matching at the start of the string.
    (?:       # Match a single field, plus the subsequent separator or the end of the line
      ("?)    # 1st capture group: the opening delimiter, if any
      (.*?)   # 2nd capture group: the (unquoted) field value
      \1      # Backreference: closing delimiter that matches the opening one
      (?:,|$) # subsequent separator or end of the line
    )
    {2}       # match 2 fields
    .*$       # match anything else on that line
  ', 
  '$2'        # replace with the last instance of what the 2nd capture group captured.
```

---

###### Variant regex solution with support for *multiline field values* and *field-internal `"` chars.*:

Handling these cases:

- makes the regex significantly more complex (multiline option `(?m)` omitted):

  - `^(?:([^"\n][^,\n]*|(?:"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"))(?:,|$)){2}`
  - For an explanation, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/kkNScZ/4) and the annotated form of the regex below.
- requires *post-processing* in order to *unescape* the escaped `"` chars. (i.e., replace `""` sequences with `"`).

Note that this again points to the fact that using a CSV parser is the simpler solution.

The code below:

- uses [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) literals (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@` / `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) to represent multiline strings.
- uses the [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET API, with post-processing of the matches using PowerShell code.
- uses `(?x)`, the inline form of the [`IgnoreWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Whitespace) regex option to allow formatting the regex for readability, using insignificant whitespace and `#`-based to-end-of-line comments.
- As in the `-replace` case, only the *last* instance of what the duplicated (repeated) capture group (`(...){2}`) captured is extracted, using `.Groups[1].Value`, resulting in just the values from the target column.

  - However, direct use of .NET APIs allows you to extract *all* column values up to and including the specified column, namely via `.Groups[1].Captures.Value` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77669440/45375) for an application of this technique.

```bash
# Sample CSV data (single, multiline string) that includes
# a field with an embedded newline, and another with an embedded
# " (escaped as "").
$csvData = @'
"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?",""
0x00030002,What do you want to eat?,
"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? fish, meat or
eggs?",""
0x00030002,"Do you want ""meat""?",
'@ 

# The annotated regex to match the $n-th field, with support
# for multiline values and embedded " chars. in double-quoted fields.
# As an aside:
#  * Regexes used directly with .NET APIs are case-*sensitive* by 
#    default, unlike when used with PowerShell's operators.
#  * This makes no difference here, but if case-insensitivity is required
#    in direct .NET API use, '(?i)' can be prepended to the regex.
# Extract the 2nd column values.
$n = 2
# Define the regex.
$re = @"
(?xm) # Parsing options: 
      # x = allow insignificant whitespace and comments
      # m = multiline mode (^ and $ match on each line)
  ^ # Start of a line
  (?: # Matches a single field plus the subsequent separator or newline
    ( # Capture group that captures an unquoted or double-quoted field
      [^"\n][^,\n]*              # unquoted, nonempty
      |                          # or
      (?:"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)")  # empty or double-quoted, includes the enclosing "
    )
    (?:,|$) # Every field must be followed by "," or the end of the line.
  )
  {$n} # duplicates the match $n times to (also) capture the $n-th field
"@

# Perform matching.                                                                                      "
[regex]::Matches(
  $csvData,
  $re
).ForEach({
  # Process each match:
  # Capture group 1 contains the $n-th captured field value:
  $rawVal = $_.Groups[1].Value
  if ($rawVal.StartsWith('"') -and $rawVal.EndsWith('"')) { # double-quoted value
    # Trim the enclosing double quotes and unescape embedded " chars.
    $rawVal.Substring(1, $rawVal.Length-2).Replace('""', '"')
  }
  else { # unquoted value
    $rawVal # output as-is
  }
}) | # Produce diagnostic output for each value, to show the boundaries. 
  ForEach-Object { '«{0}»' -f $_ }
```

Output, showing that both the multiline field value and the one with embedded `"` chars. was handled correctly:

```bash
«What do you want to eat?»
«What do you want to eat?»
«What do you want to eat? fish, meat or
eggs?»
«Do you want "meat"?»
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried regex below for your question and Group 1 value captures the wanted fields.

```
,"?(.*[^"]|)"?,
```

I verified the results on PowerShell like below.

```
[RegEx]::Matches('0x00000000,What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?,' , ',"?(.*[^"]|)"?,').groups[1].value
```

[image]

**Also you can take a look:** https://regex101.com/r/C28jBT/1

[image]

Comment: I edited my answer. Actually, I realize that in my case some quote were match as part of group 1 and I fixed it too.

Comment: it catches quotes and commas and it shouldn't

Comment: You need to use Group 1 match for the valid result. I already explain it in my answer. I also added example of PowerShell usage example as picture for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex.

```
^[^,]+,(")?(.+?)(?(1)",|,$)
```

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^      the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------
[^,]+  any character except: ',' (1 or more times
       (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------
,      ','
--------------------------------------------------
(      group and capture to \1 (optional
       (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------
  "      '"'
--------------------------------------------------
)?     end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
       quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
       repetition of the captured pattern will be
       stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------
(      group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------
  .+?    any character except \n (1 or more times
         (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------
)      end of \2
--------------------------------------------------
(?(1)  if back-reference \1 matched, then:
--------------------------------------------------
  ",     '",'
--------------------------------------------------
 |      else:
--------------------------------------------------
  ,      ','
--------------------------------------------------
  $      before an optional \n, and the end of
         the string
--------------------------------------------------
)      end of conditional on \1
```

```
$re = @'
^[^,]+,(")?(.+?)(?(1)",|,$)
'@

'"0x00000000","What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?",""',
'"0x00030002","What do you want to eat?",""',
'0x00000000,What do you want to eat? fish, meat or eggs?,',
'0x00030002,What do you want to eat?,' |
  Select-String -Pattern $re |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[2].Value }
```

Try it on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##lZBBS8NAEIXv@RWPJbAJnYRaz7K9VE9ioaCH0sqajtlKzIbdDW2x/vYYi7FeFBwYZmC@9x5MY3fsvOGq6rrYMa4wldF6uabViBKRqiQfqTRRyUUq6EhxGslpFEkx3o@/SpB4MDpgY3GwLXa6DggWrIPC89Ybwmu/wzpwWXrV40LS4HDZ9@QPh4E@x9F/wuhbewr6VUsSxwhYcMVFyBbBbesS2VyHwK7G51t@nO@eXvqBbLZvdL2ZO9uwCwfc6lAY9ify2rqZLsyAviF@zG@cbRu/nKzye121jPeu@wA).