# Get all matches after the first = and all without = with Regex Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, match

With the Windows Powershell regex I want to get, in each line, all matches after the first = excluded, even if there are others =.
It should, however, also take those lines that do not start with = and should take them from the beginning of the line to the end.

**Example of code from which I retrieve matches:**

```
ErrorMoving=You cannot=another.
ErrorTooMuchActions
=Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa
WorldErrorWait=An error has occurred.
```

**Result I want to achieve:**

```
You cannot=another.
ErrorTooMuchActions
Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa
An error has occurred.
```

What I tried to do:

```
(?<=\+?=).*
```

Incorrect result:

```
You cannot=another.

Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa
An error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `(?m)^.*?=` can work for your use case:

```bash
@'
ErrorMoving=You cannot=another.
ErrorTooMuchActions
=Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa
WorldErrorWait=An error has occurred.
'@ -replace '(?m)^.*?='
```

Results in:

```
You cannot=another.
ErrorTooMuchActions
Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa
An error has occurred.
```

See https://regex101.com/r/2FfIou/2 for regex details.

If you have an array of strings instead of a single *multi-line* string you may remove [`(?m)` (Multiline Mode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-8.0) from your pattern:

```bash
@(
    'ErrorMoving=You cannot=another.'
    'ErrorTooMuchActions'
    '=Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa'
    'WorldErrorWait=An error has occurred.'
) -replace '^.*?='
```

Comment: @Kenryoku I don't know if your comment is a question or an affirmation. You asked for a regex pattern and I provided it. You may test and see if it works for your case.

Comment: sorry I had read it wrong, I'll try it as soon as I can, but it seems it doesn't work on regex101

Comment: @Kenryoku pattern looks fine for this example, see: https://i.imgur.com/p8CI9Nx.png you just need to look at the "Substitution" box to see how the output would look

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77936804/45375), this is another case where PowerShell offers a conceptually simpler solution that doesn't require regexes:

- The [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator allows you to break a given string into tokens by a specifiable separator, while also allowing you to *limit* the count of resulting tokens (in other words: you can indirectly specify after how many instances of the separator splitting should stop).
  The return value is an array of strings containing the resulting tokens.
  If the given separator isn't present in the input string, the input string is returned as whole (in a single-element array).

  - As an aside: the separator operand is itself interpreted as a regex by default, enabling powerful splitting operations, but here all you need is `'='`
  - However, so as to be able to provide a simple way to split your sample text into *lines*, an additional `-split` operation is performed below, with regex `'\r?\n'`, which matches both Windows-format CRLF newlines (`\r\n`) and Unix-format LF-only ones (`\n`).

```bash
# Create an array of sample input lines.
$inputLines = @'
ErrorMoving=You cannot=another.
ErrorTooMuchActions
=Too many changes=.{k}=12=aa
WorldErrorWait=An error has occurred.
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Split each line into 2 tokens by '=', 
# and output the last token ([-1])
$inputLines.ForEach({ 
  ($_ -split '=', 2)[-1] 
})
```

The above produces the desired output as shown in your question, as an array-like collection of strings.

Comment: Thank you, but I preferred to have a regex so I could also use it on notepad++ in case I need it.

Comment: Understood, @Kenryoku; perhaps this answer will help future readers that don't have this requirement. In general, I encourage you to mention such requirements up front, as part of the question.